# the edge (5,4) is not painted. networkx

Tags: python, colors, networkx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DuLh.png)

```
spanning_tree = nx.dfs_tree(G)
tree_edges = spanning_tree.edges()
print("\nspanning tree:", tree_edges)

st = spanning_tree
edge_colors = ['red' if e in st.edges else 'black' for e in G.edges]
nx.draw(G, pos=my_layout, with_labels=True, edge_color=edge_colors, edgecolors='black', node_color="white", font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

how can i chang the edge_colors = [] part

Comment: The edge (5,4) will be painted red `if e in st.edges` evaluates true, which means that this edge must be one of the st.edges.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I think OP want to ask why there is no edge connecting to node `4` as `nx.dfs_tree(G)` is an DFS traversal and node `4` is connected to other nodes in original graph.

Comment: How could we know? We don't know the definition of `G`. the spanning tree s defined using `G` as data, which is unknown to us.